# Best approach to add records into DB using php/ajax/mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, methodology

Wondering if someone can suggest a better approach to the current method I have of integrating php/js/mysql.

I use this method just fine for returning sample data, setting a unique value, etc, and it works just fine (with various authentication methods to slow an attack attempt). However, I want to now add relatively large amount of data and wondering if there is a better method?

Currently I do this:

**JS**

```
$.ajax( {
    type : "GET",
    url : "_dbGetSomeData",
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(data) {
        parseData(data);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
include '_common.php'; 
include '_auth.php';

$INPUT_EMAIL= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["e"]);
$INPUT_FINGERPRINT = $_SESSION[SESH_VAR_NAME];

//--- Do some SQL stuff in the DB
?>
```

This works fine for a one-off request for data or setting one value, but can I use this method to save more data? I don't really want to start messing about with a huge querystring posts to the _db PHP file.

Comment: Use POST instead of GET, use PDO or mysqli and prepared statements instead of mysql and real_escape_string.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return bulk data?

Comment: No, I'm wanting to just set/store a lot of data. I'll look into prepared statements. Seems like a better way to do things than many async ajax calls in a loop to a php page which saves data in the local db. Cheers chaps.

Comment: DCoder, ok, read up on those, they look great and far better way to prepare my db interaction. However, it doesn't really explain how I will eventually be sending the data from the JS/HTML page (example a table object with rows) to the PHP page (via an ajax call). I want to avoid, if possible, a huge query string sent to the PHP page to then be parsed

Comment: POST doesn't send a query string. If you want to set a lot of data, you have to send it all somehow, what alternative is there?

Comment: POST will allow you to send much more data because the values are not sent as part of the query string. This is how file uploads are done, so I imagine it can handle the amount of data you would like to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you should do Ajax requests with jQuery/PHP/MySQL

**JS**

```
var postData = {
    first_name: 'Foo',
    last_name: 'Bar',
    phone: '1-555-432-1234'
};

$.post('path/to/ajax/url.php', postData)
 .done(function(response) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + response);
 });
```

**PHP**

```
// Connect to MySQL
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

// We want do some validation on the data so we can make a function called
// `validate()` if you want.
$data = validate($_POST);

$stmt = $dbh->('INSERT INTO my_table (first_name, last_name, phone) 
    VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :phone)');

$stmt->execute($data);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Much tidier than my code. Many thanks ChrisLondon