# How to properly Insert javascript variable to mysql database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Im trying to implement the solution posted in this question
[Best approach to add records into DB using php/ajax/mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027105/best-approach-to-add-records-into-db-using-php-ajax-mysql)

My code so far is like this

JS

```
function FromFlash(m1, m2, m3, m4){ 
    var postData = {
        theStream: m1,
        theLabel: m2,
        theLocation: m4,
        theStatus: m3
    };

    $.post('add_stream.php', postData)
    .done(function(response) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + response);
    });
}
```

PHP

```
//Connect to DB
...

// INSERT DATA

$data = validate($_POST);

$stmt = $dbh->('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
    VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');

$stmt->execute($data); 


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New stream added successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

I am getting this error. (line 21 refers to **$stmt = $dbh->** )

```
Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in <b>add_stream.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I checked pairing of open/close parenthesis and it is properly paired

What am I missing?

Comment: I think it's time for you to get glasses. It should be `$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
    VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');`. What you forgot is the command `prepare`.

Comment: By the way. Im not using PDO to connect to database. Im using MySQLi Procedural as described here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong in your script. You're using MySQLi OOP, not procedural. Also use the php.net manual, not w3schools.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to prepare your query :)

replace :

```
$stmt = $dbh->('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');
```

With this :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to tackle the error above but new one pops up. `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  validate() in <b>add_stream.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />`

Comment: It seem that your validate function is not defined in your add_stream.php file, be sure to add/include it on your file ;), don't forget to accept and upvote my answer bro' :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave you an upvote for leading me to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `prepare()` and $data should be an array of place holders.

```
$data = array(
':theStream'=>$_POST['theStream'],
':theLabel'=>$_POST['theLabel'],
':theLocation'=>$_POST['theLocation'],
':theStatus'=>$_POST['theStatus']
);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');

$stmt->execute($data);
```

**For ajax:**

```
var postData = {
theStream: m1,
theLabel: m2,
theLocation: m4,
theStatus: m3
};

$(".form").submit(function(){

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'target.php',
data: postData,
success:function(data){
//code to run after success
}

})

})
```

**Total code:**

```
    <?php

    include 'PDODB.php';    

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $data = array(
    ':theStream'=>$_POST['theStream'],
    ':theLabel'=>$_POST['theLabel'],
    ':theLocation'=>$_POST['theLocation'],
    ':theStatus'=>$_POST['theStatus']
    );

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Streams (theStream, theLabel, theLocation, theStatus) 
    VALUES (:theStream, :theLabel, :theLocation, :theStatus)');



    $stmt->execute($data);

    }


?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="form">Form</button>

<script>

    var postData = {
    theStream: 'qq',
    theLabel: 'ww',
    theLocation: 'ee',
    theStatus: 'rr',
    submit: 'submit'
    };

    $(".form").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:this.url,
    data: postData,
    success:function(data){
    //code to run after success
    }

    })

    })

</script>
```

Comment: I get `expecting ')' ` error. the syntax highlighting seems not correct. $_POST is black on last 3 instances but red on the first one. Is this correct? tried to correct it by adding some quotes but i got the same error

Comment: everything seems to work now on the code level but my data is not being inserted into the database.

Comment: Thanks. Did not worked for me specifically but I got useful hints from your code that led me to find this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ then i dropped the array data and use the same as per the example in that url. Working now.